# Limits of sequences and closed sets

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, proof-explanation

> I'm trying to show that if any sequence $(a_n)\in A $ and $a_n \rightarrow a.$ Then if $a\in A $ then $A$ is a closed set.

**Attempt:** I start by taking $a \not\in A $ so $a\in \mathbb{R}\backslash A$. Now if $\mathbb{R}\backslash A$ is open then $\exists \epsilon >0 $ such that $(a-\epsilon , a+ \epsilon )\cap A = \emptyset .$ So now if we suppose $\mathbb{R}\backslash A $ is closed then for each $n\in \mathbb{N} $ we can find an $a_n \in A $ such that $a_n\in (a-1/n, a+1/n ) \Rightarrow |a_n-a|<1/n $ and so $a_n\rightarrow a $. Now the next bit to complete the proof says that the above implies that $a\in A$, but how does the above imply this final statement yielding the contradiction?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/882876/a-set-a-subseteq-mathbbr-is-closed-if-and-only-if-every-convergent-sequenc

I hope the answers from here help you!

Comment: Note that $a\in A$ is an assumption, so you cannot start by taking $a\notin A$. All you need to do is to pick an arbitrary element in $A^c$ and show that this element is an interior point of $A^c$. For more details, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x\in A^c$.

**Claim:** $\exists\epsilon>0$ such that $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\subset A^c$.

Suppose that $\forall \epsilon>0$, we have $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\not\subset A^c$. This implies that for every $n\in\Bbb N$, $\exists a_n\in A$ such that $$a_n\in \bigg(x-\frac{1}{n},x+\frac{1}{n}\bigg).$$
Hence, $$a=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=x.$$
We obtain a contradiction because $a\in A$ but $x\in A^c$. This proves our claim.

$\qquad$ Thus, using the claim, $x$ is an interior point of $A^c$ which proves that $A^c$ is open and hence $A$ is closed.

Comment: How do you know that $a\in A$?

Comment: Look and read to your post? Isn't it $a\in A$?