# A set F is closed if and only if every convergent sequence in F converges to a limit in F

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, metric-spaces

$F \subseteq X$, where $X$ is a metric space.

Then $F$ is closed if and only if every convergent sequence in F converges to a limit in $F$.

**Attempt**

$ \implies$ If $F$ is closed, $F= \overline F$, but $\overline F=F \cup F'$ where $F'$ is the set of all accumulation points of $F$.

Thus, $F' \subseteq F$ which means that $F$ contains all of its limit points which means that every sequence in F converges to a limit that is in F.

Is this a valid proof for this direction?

**Edit**
After reading the comments, I should have written every ***convergent*** sequence in F converges to a limit in F.

Comment: You may find your answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/882876/a-set-a-subseteq-mathbbr-is-closed-if-and-only-if-every-convergent-sequenc

Comment: If F is the reals, your conclusion that every sequence within F converges to a limit of F, is false.

Comment: So if F contains all its limit points, it does not imply that every sequence in F converges to a limit in F?

Comment: @SnopD.: You can say for every point in $F'$ there exist a sequence in $F$ such that it converges to that point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a valid proof (but you wrote every sequence where you should have wrote every *convergent* sequence).

For the converse:
If every convergent sequence in $A$ converges to a point in $A$, then $A'\subset A$.  Thus A is closed.